# How to prove that the boundary of a cube is not a differentiable surface in the "classical" sense

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

This is a question in the context of *classical* differential geometry.  We
define a *patch* to be a differentiable function $f$ from an open subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ which is also a homeomorphism from $A$ onto its image (which we call the *trace* of $f$).  A *differentiable surface* is
defined to be a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that for each $p\in S$
there's an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $S\cap V$
is the trace of a patch.

It seems obvious that the boundary of a cube is not a differentiable surface
in this sense because of the edges and corners, but how does one prove this
rigorously?

Comment: This is a standard exercise/example. Using implicit function theorem one shows that any surface is locally a graph of a differentiable function over most planes, and in particular one of the 3 coordinate planes. At an edge or a corner of a surface of a cube this fails, so surface of a cube is not a differentiable surface.

Comment: @Max But doesn't this proof idea only work for _regular_ surfaces?

Comment: What is your definition of a regular surface?

Comment: @Max That the Jacobi matrices of the patches have to have rank 2.  I would think that this is necessary to use the implicit function theorem in the way you suggest.

Comment: Oh, right, you only require $f$ to be smooth and a homeomorphism in your definition of differentiable surface. Then the boundary of a cube is in fact a differentiable surface.  For a point on the edge a local patch is $(x,y) \to  (sign(x) e^{-1/x^2}, e^{-1/x^2}, y)$. For a vertex this is more annoying, but also doable in a similar manner, perhaps using polar coordinates.

Comment: Yikes!  That shows that my intuition was wrong all the time.  I had thought that differentiability ruled out sharp edges or cornes...

Comment: Try $t \to (t^2, t^2)$ or $t\to (t^2, t^3)$. Regularity (or, depending on context, sometimes equivalently, differentiability of the inverse) is essential.